# Moving Azure Subscription to New Mgmt Group

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-management-groups

We're looking at moving an Azure subscription under a new management group, I just wanted see if there any implications to the workloads running on the subsciption? The subscription is already under a management group, however we are moving it ot a new management group, this will not be under the same branch as the current management group, there will be some policies which I need to replicate to new management group, but thos policies restrict permissions.

Fairly sure this doesn't affect any workloads running in the subscription, but just wanted to confirm and make sure there's nothing I'm missing.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to get an answer for this question @Norrin? I am looking into doing exactly the same

Comment: @ccoutinho hi didn’t really get an answer, so doing it using powershell and extended the downtime migration period.

Comment: Thank you for you reply :) so, no workloads were affected when you did the migration?

Comment: @ccoutinhoi no workloads were affected, we didn’t have many workloads running but they were unaffected

Comment: and by any chance, was the scope of your task to move the subscription into an enterprise-scale landing zone architecture? The subscriptions I have to move will be moved to a VWan under an enterprise-scale landing zone architecture, and I am afraid that might break connectivity

Comment: It was an enterprise architecture, but not using vWAN although it was a standard hub and spoke design. The risks of moving are minimal as the subscription isn't physically moved, its more an organisational structure, if that makes sense

Comment: it does! So, in your case, the migration was within the hub and spoke, and you were not moving the subscription into the hub and spoke?

Comment: Not moving it into, it was already within the hub and spoke architecture, however the management group (which was managing DEV) needs to be removed and a mgmt group for QA added, but not added as in it didn't exist, it already existed managing other QA subscriptions, but we needed to add the subscription to it

Answer (score 0):

This will not effect most Azure resource types such as VirtualMachines or StorageAccounts. However, if you have Azure Policy assignments, Quotas or Role Assignments on the original MG they will not apply to the subscription anymore.